# c++ breaks on class function

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, class-design

i have created this class for mesh loading it works but i added this new function to help speed up the loading.  when i call the function my program breaks/stops.
here is my function

```
bool CXFileEntity::LoadXFile(const std::string &filename, int startAnimation, CXFileEntity *entity, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev)
{
    // We only support one entity so if it already exists delete it
    if (entity)
    {
        delete entity;
        entity=0;
    }

    // Create the entity
    entity=new CXFileEntity(d3ddev);
    if (Load(filename))
    {
        delete entity;
        entity=0;
        return false;
    }

    SetAnimationSet(startAnimation);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Breaks/stops where? In this function? Another function?

Comment: Off-topic: What happens when `Load` throws an exception? You have a `delete` in your code, that's bad. Like I've said before, you need to **stop** and get a beginner not-game-oriented C++ book and learn good C++ *first*. Also, `delete 0;` is perfectly fine, everything above `// Create the entity` should be replaced with `delete entity; entity = 0;`. (Though, again, it shouldn't even be there; it should be something along the lines of `entity.reset()`, where `entity` is a smart pointer.)

Comment: you need to give more info mate. like, what errors are you getting when the program crashes

Comment: sorry guys the problem wasn't in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Wait... I hadn't realized that this function is a **member of** the CXFileEntity class. It doesn't look like it's a static method, either. So in order to call this function, you already need to have instantiated a CXFileEntity object! Therefore, it's likely that you absolutely do not want to be either deleting or creating CXFileEntity objects **inside** of this method. (If you truly only allow one entity to exist at a time, you'll be effectively deleting 'this' and then trying to re-create it. That doesn't work, no way, no how.)

I'm leaving the earlier answer in place in hopes that it will still provide you some clue about how pointers work.

---

You'd do better to give more information, such as **where** and **how** the program breaks.

But this is clearly wrong:

```
CXFileEntity *entity,
```

because it means that the new object allocated by

```
entity=new CXFileEntity(d3ddev);
```

will not be seen by the caller. (entity is a local variable, so changes to it won't be seen outside of the local scope.)

Try changing the code to pass entity as a pointer to a pointer:

```
CXFileEntity **entity,
```

which will mean changing the code inside the function to match:

```
if (*entity)
{
    delete *entity;
    *entity=0;
}

// Create the entity
*entity=new CXFileEntity(d3ddev);

// etc.
```

You'll also have to change the caller to pass a pointer to a pointer. And for goodness' sake, make sure that the first time you pass the pointer in, it's initialized to 0:

```
CXFileEntity *the_entity = 0;
...
```